# Zebra rows in xslt

Tags: xml, xslt

I am creating a table from xml using xslt, and I want every other  to be a different class.

Here is the xml:

```
<interfaces>
  <interface id="250" name="112test" odd="1"></interface>
  <interface id="251" name="113test" odd="0"></interface>
</interfaces>
```

Here is the relevant part of the xslt I've tried:

```
<xsl:template match="interfaces">
  <xsl:for-each select="interface">
    <xsl:choose>
      <xsl:when test="@odd = '1'">
        <tr class="odd">
      </xsl:when>
      <xsl:otherwise>
        <tr>
      </xsl:otherwise>
    </xsl:choose>
  </xsl:for-each>
</xsl:template>
```

How do I get this working? Or is there a better way of doing this, for instance by checking if the attribute exists instead of checking its value?

Comment: http://www.java2s.com/Tutorial/XML/0100__XSLT-stylesheet/Changestyleforevenandodd.htm

Comment: What is it that's not working with your current approach? Is it the fact that your `<tr>` elements are unclosed, and you're trying to avoid duplicating the content logic? Or is there some other aspect of this that you don't like, like the redundant addition of this "odd" attribute at the source?

Comment: The `<tr>` elements are closed, but I removed any unnecessary code. It was the odd attribute I didn't like.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The perfect solution ended up being a combination of user639175 and Matthew Wilson's answers:

```
<xsl:if test="position() mod 2 = 1">
   <xsl:attribute name="class">odd</xsl:attribute>
</xsl:if>
```

Answer (score 3):

```
<xsl:choose>
  <xsl:when test="position() mod 2 = 1">odd</xsl:when>
  <xsl:otherwise>even</xsl:otherwise>
</xsl:choose>
```

Oscilliate between even/odd nodes ...

Answer (score 2):

Untested, but something like the following should work.

```
<tr>
   <xsl:if test="@odd = '1'">
      <xsl:attribute name="class">odd</xsl:attribute>
    </xsl:if>
    ... other stuff here
</tr>
```

Answer (score -2):

Save yourself a headache and use JQuery or your framework of choice if it has appropriate selectors.

```
$(‘tr’:odd).addClass('stripe');
```

or CSS 3

```
tr:nth-child(odd) { background-color:#eee; }
```

Keep the markup clean.

Comment: This is a business application so I have to support IE6+ (otherwise I would have gone with the CSS3 solution) and I haven't got the privileges to "install" jQuery.

Comment: I addressed the problem, not the OP's challenges in their chosen approach. If the OP said "I'm trying to drive screws using a hammer, how do I get this working", answers that fail to call out that the hammer is the wrong tool are inappropriate.