# Applying zebra pattern to table created by xsl

Tags: xml, variables, xslt

I want to apply zebra pattern (i.e. applying different background color to odd and even rows) on a table. 
All the rows are generated dynamically using  conditions. i.e. if I have 10 records in database then, it is possible that only 4 or 5 will be present in the table.

To apply zebra pattern, I need to check the pattern for previous row as rows are created dynamically. After some googling, I found that variables in xsl are immutable. Hence, I can't increment value of a variable in one if condition and check the same in the next condition.

Any suggestions for the same?

Comment: Take a look at the results of http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=zebra+row+[xslt] and try to apply one of the solutions when you're creating your rows dynamically.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Zebra rows in xslt](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6955098/zebra-rows-in-xslt)

Comment: It would be helpful if you could provide an example XML and the conditions to filter to the rows that you want zebra striped in the output. Also a sample of the desired output. It is likely that you need to apply the right filters to select the items for output and could then apply standard MOD logic to toggle the zebra stripes. However, we can't assist unless we know more about your inputs, criteria, and desired output.